# Show Toolbar after first item of recyclerview is scrolled offscreen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

I have a recyclerview in which the first item is always inflated as a header with transparent status bar. When the first item is scrolled offscreen, a toolbar is made visible on the screen. But the problem is the transparent status bar is covering half of the toolbar. I want the toolbar to be aligned below the status bar. I can't use collapsing toolbar as the header element is part of the recyclerview. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share screenshots of the problem?

Comment: @mrtcnkryln I can't share the screenshots here. I just want the theme of the acitivity to change from Transparent status bar to Translucent status bar when the toolbar bar is made visible. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: please check, Hope this will help!! https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/

Comment: @KalpeshRupani This is different from what I want.

Comment: @NIKHILAGGARWAL you can achieve your operation by taking reference from that link. At least you try because its all about scrolling logic. All the method of recyclerview scroll is there. So you just do some modification. Hope you will achieve!!

Comment: @KalpeshRupani Thanks for the suggestion. I have already achieved to show the toolbar when I scroll the recyclerview. I want the toolbar to be shown below the status bar and the theme of activity should change from transparent status bar to translucent status bar. :)

Comment: @NIKHILAGGARWAL Happy Coding :)